# Why is my wrapped int not retaining the changes made by this method?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

```
private static String getArgValue(String[] argsString, int[] jIndex, String classTag) {

    String thisToken;

    for( ; jIndex[0]<argsString.length ; jIndex[0]++) {
        System.out.println("jIndex[0]: " + jIndex[0]);

        if (condition) {
            // yadda yadda yadda
            jIndex[0]++;
            System.out.println("jIndex[0]: " + jIndex[0]);
            return retString;
        }
    }

    return retString;
}
```

I've tried wrapping it both with `Integer` and with an array, but neither have made changes to the original `i` variable.  How it is called:

```
int[] j = new int[1];

for(int i=2; i< argsString.length; i++) {
    // yadda yadda yadda
    System.out.println("opening i: " + i);
    j[0] = i;

    thisArgValueString = getArgValue(argsString, j, thisArgClassString);
    System.out.println("closing i: " + i);
}
```

Example output:

```
opening i: 2
jIndex[0]: 2
jIndex[0]: 3
jIndex[0]: 5
closing i: 2
```

Comment: You never make another assignment to `i`, apart from the loop increment, so why do you think it should change?

Comment: He is confused about the difference between changing the contents of an object and changing the contents of a primitive variable.

Comment: @nnythm Sorry, I was AFK for breakfast.  I understand the difference between the two (hence the reason why I am attempting to use a wrapper in the first place), but what I didn't realize is that `j[0]=i;` simply makes a copy of `i`'s value instead of making `j[0]` a reference to the `i` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing your int holder and not i itself:

```
System.out.println("closing i: " + j[0]);
```

Or you can simply reassign i:

```
i = j[0];
System.out.println("closing i: " + i);
```

Your original varialbe `i` will not change by itself as it is a primitive type. Integer is also not useful as it is immutable. So the code you provided is essentially the correct approach. You just have to understand, that `j[0] = i` only assigns the value of `i` to `j[0]` and does not link the content of `j[0]` to `i`. So you could just work with `j[0]` from that point on (like the first code in this post) or reassign `i` back from `j[0]` (like the second code in this post).

Answer (score 1):

An `Integer` is immutable, but you were apparently trying to use it as if it was mutable.  That won't work.

On the other hand, an `int[1]` can be used as a mutable int holder ...

... and the reason it doesn't *appear to* work in your example is that in the last print statement you are printing `i` rather than the `j` holder that you updated in the `getArgValue` call.  Change the last statement to:

```
    System.out.println("closing i: " + j[0]);
```

Remember, this is *simulated* call-by-reference, not real call-by-reference.  You have to jump through the hoops in the right order for the simulation to work.

Comment: The example code given uses an array wrapper.  Any idea why it's not working?  Seems strange!

Comment: The array is mutated, but i will not be mutated, because i is not an object reference, it is a primitive.  The reason that making the int[1] would work is that int[1] is an object reference to an object which has mutable contents.  You are referring to the same object in the method and in the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

Java is pass by value, and the behavior that you're expecting, which is that the contents of i be changed, happens consistently with objects, where the value that you're passing is an object reference.  However, with primitives, such as chars, ints, and doubles, you are passing the actual data itself.  What you are putting into j[0] is not the variable i, but instead the contents of i.  Hence, there are now two memory positions with the same contents--j[0] and i.  However, when you change j[0], i is unaffected, because it is completely unrelated--you just once copied the contents of j[0] into i.  When you pass an object into a method, you're actually passing in the object reference, so you are referring to the same object.  By casting i to an Integer, you are autoboxing it, which is to say, you are making a copy of i, and then wrapping it with an object Integer, and then destroying the object.

Answer (score 1):

your code snippet shows you have misconceptions about what array mutability and pass by reference means.

Let me give you a more simplified example which removes all the non-essential crap thats around the core of the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int numberToModify = 42;
   int [] arr = new int[1];
   arr = numberToModify;
   System.println("numberToModify="+numberToModify );
   System.println("arr[0]="+arr[0]);
   doStuff(arr);
   System.println("numberToModify="+numberToModify );
   System.println("arr[0]"+arr[0]);
}

private static void doStuff(int[] array){
   array[0] = 100;  
}
```

what you should see is printed out is

```
numberToModify=42
arr[0]=42
numberToModify=42
arr[0]=100
```

in your code example, you seem to expect that the variable `i` (here it is `numberToModify`) should have also changed when the array is modified inside the method. It doesn't, because the array holds an actual value type (since `int`s are primative, and primatives are passed by value).

Answer (score 0):

So you want the variable i to retain all the changes done to it? Have you tried declaring it as a Integer object? int is a primitive type, so you cant pass it by reference, wrapping it in anything will just assign its value. Try to do something like this:

```
for(Integer i=2; i< argsString.length; i++) {
// yadda yadda yadda
System.out.println("opening i: " + i);
j[0] = i;

thisArgValueString = getArgValue(argsString, j, thisArgClassString);
System.out.println("closing i: " + i);
```

}

and see if that solves your problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this solution won't work, it means that object reference in getArgValue isn't referring to 2 anymore, but i still is.